# Query Multiple Values in a List Box

Tags: ms-access, vba

Here's my situation. Haven't found any reliable source for this specifically.
I need to Query Multiple selections from a List Box in a form.
Qry is qryMetrics, 
Table is Metrics, 
Field is Job Description, 
List Box is lstJobDesc,

I have the ListBox that shows a list of Job Descriptions and a Button that Runs the Query. I can select one Job Description and run the query and return the 1 I selected. I need to be able to let the user select more than one value and return the query of the Values selected. I understand that Multi Select returns Null if anything other than None is selected, but how to I get Extended or Simple to work while returning the multiple values selected from the form and return all when nothing is selected?

Comment: Show your query that works with one selection. You can add a VBA loop to build the query using an IN clause for multiple selections - but you don't have any sample code or SQL to show us?

Comment: Here is the link for it. I am not sure what I could provide. The list was created without much coding.  As you can see that the qryWhseMetrics has a Job Description List. I want to be able to select multiple descriptions and return their values in the qry.                https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8FsW0sImRM3TW85alR3a0xBWm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your query. Not your whole database

Comment: Text = ""

    For i = 0 To Me.lstJobDesc.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstJobDesc.Selected(i) Then
            Text = Text & Me.lstJobDesc.ItemData(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
        
    If Text = "" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.lstJobDesc.ListCount - 1
            Text = Text & Me.lstJobDesc.ItemData(i) & vbNewLine
        Next i
    End If
    MsgBox Text

Answer (score 0):

```
'''Listbox - Multiselect property=Simple
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    Text = ""

    For i = 0 To Me.lstJobDesc.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstJobDesc.Selected(i) Then
            Text = Text & Me.lstJobDesc.ItemData(i) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i

    If Text = "" Then
        For i = 0 To Me.lstJobDesc.ListCount - 1
            Text = Text & Me.lstJobDesc.ItemData(i) & vbNewLine
        Next i
    End If
    MsgBox Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am adding this into my code but nothing is happening. I am wondering if I am incorporating this wrong. Any further input would be great.

Comment: Try to debug the code, and let me know where you are getting issue.